# How can I add style sheet link to my wordpress page

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

Example: I have following HTML code and where should I place that `bootstrap.min.css` link. If I place that link in HTML code itself, when the page is published it's not loading the CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Thumbnail</h2>
  <p>The .img-thumbnail class creates a thumbnail of the image:</p>            
  <img src="cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236"> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If this is not working for you then as an alternate download this css file and place it in `your_theme - > css -> bootstrap.min.css`. After placing it inside css folder of your theme directory, call it like this from your header.php `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">`. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) in your functions.php:

```
function custom_wp_enqueue_style() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapcdn', "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" );
}
add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_wp_enqueue_style' );
```

The second parameter can be the path to the folder in your server where you have your bootstrap.

Comment: I have tried this & still css is not loading properly. I have placed my html code & custom_wp_enqueue_style code in gist, please tell me what i'm missing .
(I'm placeing html code in my wordpress page)
(https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a2055361501a954c04ac976db0044719)

Comment: It works fine for me...

Comment: Maybe are you using a cache plugin on your wp or your server? And you wrote "function.php" on the gist. It should be "functions.php", I assume it's a typo, but check if the name is okay, please.

Comment: Thank you..:) I have installed wordpress in my local system & checking. Yes its functions.php not function.php

Comment: If I add link in custom_wp_enqueue_style function then is it required to add link in my html file ?

Comment: No, in fact is used to not add that link in your header, and have a bit more control over your scripts and styles files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load css then you have to simply add single php line before css link.
Call this line before href and src link.

```
<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/
```

using this line you can load all type of css and image also.
here you are trying to link bootstrap 
example:-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

now your css will work.

Comment: You don't need to use this function to call file from online link (link that have started with `http://`). This function should be use only to call those file that are present in theme's directory. The example you have shown in second code line of your, that won't work, So change the file path after the function.

Comment: Thank you :). I have included php line like this (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4a2ebd0caed980b031a7633edb9ea666).  Still its not loading css :(.

Comment: wow 2 upvotes on a wrong answer!!

Comment: For me its loading page like this (https://postimg.org/image/ozzichkgj/) & here its gist link for my code (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1fbee26ef1da1cefdea8c37c1e499353). Please tell me what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

If other methods don't work, you can always use @import inside another css file:

@import url("stylesheet_2.css");

This will work, but may not be as fast since it is waiting for the other css to load before loading the rest of the css.

Sometimes there's no other choice, in case it's a website that you have limited access to, or complicated setup, etc.